# Change the class and get values on click in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Changer la devises <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-currency">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" id="cad" data-sign="$CAN">Canadian Dollar</a></span></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="usd" data-sign="$">American dollar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="eur" data-sign="€">Euro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="mxn" data-sign="$">Mexican Peso</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On click on any currency, I want to change the active class and get the `id` and the `data-sign`.

What I tried:

```
$('.dropdown-currency > li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dropdown-currency > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    changeCurrency();
});

function changeCurrency() {
    var currency = $('.dropdown-currency > li.active > a').attr('id');
    var sign = $('.dropdown-currency > li.active > a').data('sign');

    alert(currency);
    alert(sign);
}
```

But it doesn't work...

Could you please help me?

https://jsfiddle.net/up1v5j0z/1/

Comment: If I understand you right, I think you forgot to add the `> a` at line 3:
https://jsfiddle.net/up1v5j0z/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.dropdown-currency li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dropdown-currency li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    changeCurrency();
});

function changeCurrency() {
    var currency = $('.active a').attr('id');
    var sign = $('.active a').data('sign');

    alert(currency);
    alert(sign);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1x4qeo37/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the click function to the following:

```
$('.dropdown-currency > li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dropdown-currency > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    var currency = $(this).attr('id');
    var sign = $(this).data('sign');

    alert(currency);
    alert(sign);
});
```

Comment: It don't remove the initial active item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('.dropdown-currency > li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dropdown-currency > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    changeCurrency(e);
});

function changeCurrency(e) {
    var currency = $(e.target).attr('id');
    var sign = $(e.target).data('sign');
    alert(currency);
    alert(sign);
}
```

If you prefer to have a separate function for getting the values. Just sending the event object as parameter to the function.

Comment: It don't put the active class for the new item.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this code?

```
$('.dropdown-currency > li > a').click(function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    alert($(this).attr('data-sign'));
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dropdown-currency > li').removeClass();
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});

https://jsfiddle.net/up1v5j0z/8/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/up1v5j0z/5/

> Hope this will help

Comment: It don't remove the initial active item class.

Comment: Try the updated one. I manage color change for your reference.